# How to cancel unload event of an Iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I am trying to catch unload event of an Iframe, and prevent navigation, using the following code:

```
<iframe
      onLoad={() => {
        iframeEl.current.contentWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
      }}
...
```

But it keeps navigating to the undesired destination.
What is the correct way of stopping it?